# is there any way to restore lost file after svn:revert operation in NETBEANS?

Tags: svn, netbeans, restore, revert

I updated my project, written tons of code and after that i updated again. i got some conflicts so I reverted changes (thinking that i will be back to moment before last update). Unfortunately i lost all my code.

Is it possible to restore it? ( I work in netbeans with svn)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old versions should still be in the "Local history".

Right click on the file then choose "Local history -> Show local history"

From there you can diff the old version to your current one and retrieve the old code